# declaring variables in MongoDB using $lookup with let and pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup, aggregation

I'm trying to add a **like** feature to my site. I've made a **likes** collection with the following schema. I'm using custom _id to avoid creating an extra index.

```json
{
  _id: {
    postId: ObjectId,
    userId: ObjectId
  }
}
```

I have a route on my server which searches the posts collection using MongoDB **aggregations**. I'm trying to add a **$lookup** stage to the current pipeline in order to add a **liked** property with the type of **Boolean** indicating wether or not the post has been liked by the user. Here's the **$lookup** stage which is not working (**liked** returns an empty array all the time even when there's a corresponding like document):

```json
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'likes',
    let: { likedPostId: '$_id.postId', likerUserId: '$_id.userId' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match:
        { $expr:
          { $and:
            [
              { $eq: [
                '$$likerUserId',
                  ObjectId('12345')
              ]},
              { $eq: [
                  '$$likedPostId',
                  '$_id'
              ]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'liked'
  }
}
```

I think the problem is the **variables** don't actually hold the values I'm expecting them to. Is there any way to solve this? Also if you know a simpler way to implement this I'd appreciate if you share it with me.

I've tried comparing two identical **ObjectId()** instances to ensure **ObjectId** instances can be compared using **$eq** operator. Also tried defining **nested variables** like the ones in the code snippet above on a different **nested field**. the only different thing in this problem is that I'm trying to pull properties outside the **_id field**.

P.S. I know the **liked** property would be an **Array** instead of a **Boolean**. But I'm thinking of converting that into a **Boolean** in the next stage. But that's not the problem right now.

Comment: I think a simpler way to implement it would be by adding a liked field in your post model; this liked field would be an array of user ids. This way you can query the post directly if it was 'liked' and by whom.

Comment: @FranciscoMarão i disagree, this design pattern is extremely bad on large scale imo.

Comment: Also @amiratak88 your syntax is correct, you should triple-check a match is suppose to be found.

Comment: @tomslabbaert Thanks for the comment. Can u please elaborate more on that especially the triple-check.

Comment: Not much to say, the syntax is right. i just double checked on my local and got a match. meaning i'm assuming once of the ID's you want to match isn't identical.

Comment: @tomslabbaert Got it. u meant triple-check the syntax and results. I thought it's a MongoDB expression. LOL. I think I got the syntax mixed up tho and mickl is right.

Comment: I didn't even notice the collections were mixed up, Mb
Regardless the syntax itself is correct.

Comment: @tomslabbaert I do agree with you, but he asked for a simpler way, not a more scalable one;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the other way around. If you're running `$lookup` on `likes` collection then `let` section's goal is to define variables that refer to the collection that you're running aggregation on. On the other hand you can refer to fields defined in `likes` collection using single dollar sign inside of `pipeline`. Try:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'likes',
        let: { id: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [
            { $match:
                { $expr:
                { $and:
                    [
                    { $eq: [
                        '$_id.userId',
                        ObjectId('12345')
                    ]},
                    { $eq: [
                        '$_id.postId',
                        '$$id'
                    ]}
                    ]
                }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: 'liked'
    }
}
```

EDIT: Please take a look at the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

> let
>   Optional. Specifies variables to use in the pipeline field stages. Use the variable expressions to access the fields from the documents **input** to the $lookup stage.
>
> The pipeline cannot directly access the input document fields.
>   Instead, first define the variables for the input document fields, and
>   then reference the variables in the stages in the pipeline.

Comment: I've edited the answer moving couple of dollars around:). Is that what you're suggesting? I've tried this thinking maybe I can't pull variables out inside **let** and instead pull them out once I want to use them. Still no luck :(

Comment: Also either way works once working with a field other that **_id**

Comment: @Amiratak88 I've just rejected your edit. The thing is that you should use $lookup the other way around. As the doc says, let is for input collection, not for the collection defined by `from` statement

Comment: Could u please elaborate on **the other way around**? U mean change the **from** property?

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment :). Here's the EDIT:
The thing is I think in your answer inside the `$and` array, `$$id` refers to **like._id** and `$id` refers to **post._id** according to this [page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) from MongoDb docs. (See the 8th code snippet from the bottom where let is used). But i think u r using it the other way around.

Comment: Also ignore this last comment:). Just checked the same code snippet i referred u to and I think u r absolutely right. Let me try this and let u know the result.

Comment: Okay just tried it and it works. Thanks a lot mickl. And sorry for being a little stubborn at first.

Comment: I edited ur answer to avoid a syntactical error when defining a variable starting with `_` in `_id`. I changed it to `id` and everything's fine now.

Comment: @Amiratak88 gotcha, approved your edit, thanks for accepting the answer :)